# How can I set multiple ckeditors of same class even if we add new ckeditor by appending on click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, multiple-instances

I am planning to use multiple ckeditors on a single page. I need to append ckeditor on click a button but it's not working on the appended ckeditor.
I have tried to insert the same class and call all ckeditors like "querySelectorAll('.editor')"

It's working properly on every '.editor' class. But my problem is with the ckeditor appended after clicking a button.

I found the '.editor' class has added by inspecting the source code. I think It will work, Now I need help.

```
    <div class="editors">
        <div class="editor">
          <p>Editor 1 here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="editor">
          <p>Editor 2 here</p>
        </div>
        </div>

        <button class="add-editor">Add New Editor</button>


        <script>
        $('.add-editor').click(function(){
         $('.editors').append(' <div class="editor"><p>Editor 3 here (Editor Not Loading here)</p></div>')
         });

 var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.editor');
  for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
    InlineEditor.create(allEditors[i]);
  }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that you only want to enable CKEditor to new editors. If you do it to existing ones, you'll get errors. You could solve that by adding an `.enabled` class to them, and that way, when you add a new one, you won't affect old ones.

```js
// Once on page load, for existing editors
$(document).ready(enableEditors);
// When you click on the button
$('.add-editor').click(function() {
  var count = $('.editor').length + 1;
  $('.editors').append('<div class="editor"><p>Editor ' + count  + ' here</p></div>');
  enableEditors();
});

function enableEditors() {
  $('.editor:not(.enabled)').ckeditor().addClass('.enabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="editors">
  <div class="editor">
    <p>Editor 1 here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="editor">
    <p>Editor 2 here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add-editor">Add New Editor</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `CKEDITOR.replace('editor');` after creating the dynamic content to setup CKEDITOR on it.

Let me know if this isn't what you were hoping for.

> **N.B.** Not sure why it's throwing an error, despite working. If anyone knows please let me know and I'll update the answer.

---

## Demo

```js
// Create click event for add button
$("#add-input").click(function() {

  // Add new input to #input-list
  $("#input-list").append('<input name="editor">');

  // Replace newly added editor with CKEDITOR
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>


<button id="add-input">Add editor</button>

<div id="input-list"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry If I can't make you clear about my problem. Here's the fiddle of my actual problem https://jsfiddle.net/bhusalhari99/8mLxr0n1/

Comment: Updated - it now adds a dynamic editor and converts it